# How do I write a regex to match anything inside a single quote except any date format like 'MM/DD/YYYY'?

Tags: regex

In `$i = "select to_char('MM/DD/YYYY'), 'JOHN' createdby from dual";`

I want the regex to fetch only `JOHN` and not `MM/DD/YYYY`.

I tried something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/Mc1zIa/1):

```
\'(?![MM|DD|YY].*[DD|MM|YY].*[YY|MM|DD].*).*?\'
```

Comment: When you say `'MM/DD/YYYY'`, do you literally mean the string  `'MM/DD/YYYY'` (like in your regex attempt), or do you really mean actual date strings, like  `'10/11/2012'`? Do you care about strictly validating the date, e.g. the string:  `'99/99/9999'` should still match, because it's an invalid date?

Comment: I literally meant the date formatstring 'MM/DD/YYYY'. But 'any date format' in the question, I mean 'MM/DD/YYYY', 'DD/MM/YYYY' etc..

Comment: That's not very specific... Is `MY/YD/MMDY` a valid format? Do you *really* want to match `[MDY]{2}\/[MDY]{2}\/[MDY]{4}`??!

Comment: My concern here is not the date format. It is, to pick up patterns within single quotes except valid date formats (I use any one of these 3 - 'MM/DD/YYYY' or 'DD/MM/YYYY' or 'YYYY/MM/DD').

Comment: Which *specific* regex format/language? This is much easier to do with ERE than BRE or ERE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for this regex - `\'(?!((\))|(M{2}|D{2}|Y{2,4}).*?(M{2}|D{2}|Y{2,4}).*?(M{2}|D{2}|Y{2,4}.*))).*?\'`

Have a look [here](https://regex101.com/r/PiKo7G/1).

Comment: I think this requires the date quotation to be followed by a closing paren. If that works for you, great, although you didn't stipulate that in the question. Are you required to use only extended RE or is PCRE (Perl-syntax) an option? What tool or language are you using? I'm curious about why my answer doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with `\'((MM\/DD\/YYYY|DD\/MM\/YYYY|YYYY\/MM\/DD)\'(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[^']*)\'`. (This is Perl regex or PCRE, by the way, which the link the questioner gave indicates, although she doesn't mention it in the question.) The way it works is that two expressions will match: Either a date format in quotes (followed by some verbs we'll get to shortly), or a quote, followed by any number of non-quote characters, and a closing quote. Now, if the first alternative (i.e. the date) matches, the special verb `(*SKIP)` means stop backtracking, which is necessary because otherwise the r.e. engine will try to match the ending quote to the second alternative (from the `man 3 pcrepattern` page: "`(*SKIP)` signifies that whatever text was matched leading up to it cannot be part of a successful match"). This is also the purpose of the quote in the middle. The verb `(*FAIL)` means fail this regular expression immediately (from the `man` page: "This verb  causes a matching failure, forcing backtracking to occur. It is equivalent to `(?!)` but easier to read"). In other words, if we have matched the subexpression so far, abort and move on. Together with the `(*SKIP)`, this forces matching to end at this point in the subject and to continue with subsequent text.

Answer (score 0):

You may accomplish this partially by regex and partially resorting to the language you're using regex from (I'm assuming PHP, but should be pretty similar with others.)

First, match all undesired patterns and after that, using alternaltion, match your quoted string pattern with the substring between quotes captured in a group. Then, in the calling language, collect all non-null first captured groups:

```
preg_match_all("~'MM/DD/YYYY'|'DD/MM/YYYY'|'YYYY/MM/DD'|'(.*?)'~", $i, $matches);
$non_dates = array_filter($matches[1]);
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/5ZIsoJ